# Why is "Build Project" greyed-out in Eclipse Helios CDT even though the makefile and source exist?

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I can't build my project.

I created a new CDT project in Eclipse Helios and told it to use existing source and makefile -- both, of which, appear correctly in the Package and Project views. The "Project" menu has both "Build All" and "Build Project" grayed-out, however, so it's impossible to build the project. "Build Automatically" is unchecked. During project creation, I told the wizard to use the Linux gcc(1) toolchain. I've been unable to find anything under Project->Properties or Window->Preferences that enables the "Build Project" feature. The Window->Preferences->Build display shows only one tab labeled "Error Parsers".

How can I enable the "Build Project" command?

Answer (score 7):

When you uncheck the

> Project :: Build Automatically

button, then it will show you the option to

> Project :: Build All

Answer (score 4):

This may not be related to your issue if you're using a custom toolchain....

My experience with eclipse is that it sometimes doesn't quite grok the context of the file in the current editor.  Have you tried right-clicking the project and selecting build there?  Make sure you choose the actual project and not a source file.  Also, make sure your source file is recently saved.

Usually, after I use the method above then the correct "Run As" and "Build" options will appear regardless of the current active editor file.  I have this issue with Java, JUnit, C/C++, etc with Helios on Linux.

Comment: I'm using the Linux gcc(1) toolchain that was identified as a candidate by CDT. The context menu obtained by button-3 clicking on the project in the Project Explorer doesn't contain a build option -- regardless of the save-state of an edited file.

Comment: I may be confused, but I thought there was a build option in that context menu for the CDT.... try checking "Run as" and see if that will build it for you.  As I mentioned, in the JDT, I sometimes have to use that "Run As" option before it will let me use the button-bar at the top to run/debug/etc.  We only use the JDT/Apex here at work, so I can't readily verify. :\

Comment: The "Run As" entry in the context menu of the project in the Project Explorer has a (sub)context menu with "Run Configurations..." as its only entry. The entries in the pop-up window that subsequently appears don't seem appropriate for building a project.

Comment: It seems like you're having a different issue than the one I'm describing.  When I do not have an option to build in the CDT (or Run, or JUnit run, etc) using the Run command, right clicking the project, etc (steps listed above) usually fixes it.  I'm not sure what other suggestions I could provide - I use the CDT pretty often with the default linux gcc toolchain without the issue you describe.

Answer (score 4):

I've discovered the cause of my problem: selecting the wrong "New Project" wizard. I selected the "Makefile Project with Existing Code" wizard because the source and makefile already existed. I should have selected the "C Project" wizard and told it not to create a makefile. The result of doing the latter is that the "Build Project" entry of the "Project" menu is not grayed-out.

Apparently, the "Makefile Project with Existing code" is a generic wizard rather than one specific to C/C++ projects.