# Eclipse CDT, How to compile a single C++ file?

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation

I am trying to compile a single file. The project has got an external make-file. I have turned off "Build Automatically". Right click on the file, I do see "Build selected File(s)" context menu, but it is disabled (grayed out).

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: See this if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656252/why-is-build-project-greyed-out-in-eclipse-helios-cdt-even-though-the-makefile

Additional help in case you need:

1. makefile is created automatically under Debug folder. If you don't want to use that, you could try placing your own makefile in the folder 
2. Navigate to project properties --> C/C++ Build --> Make file generation --> and untick "Generate Make files automatically". 
3. If you don't already have set your build configurations, go to Project properties --> Run/Debug Settings --> Update your project settings

Comment: @animageofmine Its probably better just to create an `Empty Makefile` project type under `C++ Projects` wizzard.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the project as a `Makefile` project?

Open the `Makefile` in the editor and then select the `Outline` window (should be on the right). If its not visible open it using menu: `Window -> Show View -> Outline`. While you're there make sure the `Make Target` view is open with menu: `Window ->Show View -> Make Target`.

In the `Outline` window you should see the `Makefile` symbols and targets listed. Select the targets you want to use (like `all` and `clean`), right click them, then add them to the `Make Target` window.

Once they appear in the `Make Target` window, just double-click on them to invoke *make*.

**Outline** window of `Makefile`:

[image]

**Make Target** window.

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for these elaborated comments! I did what you said. I have got this build-target: build: make -f objs/Makefile, but when I change the C code and say "build", I get the message: "no rule to make target 'build'. Stop."

Comment: @BehzadPirvali You shouldn't need to add flags to your make command to tell it to run a specific `Makefile`. Just open `objs/Makefile` in the editor, go to the `Outline` view and add the *targets*. It should then just work by double clicking on the targets in the `Make Target` view.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Yes, I can of course. In my case, I am writing an Nginx module. So, the Makefile is to build the Nginx. The Makefile is generated automatically. In the auto-generated Makefile, I do not  see the changed file being associated to a target, though :)